# iPad PhoneGap map not showing

Tags: xcode, google-maps, cordova, xcode5

I have the following html;

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

and if have some js;

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

function onDeviceReady () {
    navigator.notification.alert("Yup, it works!",function(){},"","");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCurrentPositionSuccess, getCurrentPositionError);
};

function getCurrentPositionSuccess(position) {
alert(123);
    //alert(position.coords.latitude);
    currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: currentPosition,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
}
```

Obviously all the above is a snip but all the key players are in place.

All this worked great on my PC and using Safari.  However, when I moved over to the mac, xcode and phonegap, ***the map no longer displays***.

alert(123) never happens and the `getCurrentPositionError` function is called.

The error is `code 2, kclerrordomain error 0`

I get the alert that the app want's to use my location though.

Any help here would be great.

I am using xcode 5.0.1 on Mavericks with phonegap 3.1 for iPad.

**edit**

If I use the Retina simulator I can get back the location but not if i use the ipad sim.  Why would that be?